# Having issues finding ios elements using wdio Error: element still not displayed after 20000ms

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, appium, wdio

I'm using this exact same code and it's running fine on BrowserStack using a .ipa file since BrowserStack has real devices. But when I'm running the same thing on my local simulator using a .app file its giving me the following error.

Error: element ("//XCUIElementTypeTextField[@name="domain-input"]") still not displayed after 20000ms

Not sure what the issue is but I have to get this to work on the simulator since our budget wasn't approved for BrowserStack.

[Here's the Appium inspector for the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v8sH.png)
[Here's what the element looks like on the dev side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmoeo.png)
[And here's the code on my side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6qs4.png)

Note: this is happening for all the elements I'm using they are all working on BrowserStack but not simulator.